# Array Random Access C++

Tags: c++, polymorphism, dynamic-arrays, derived-class, dynamic-cast

I'm probably going to confuse myself while writing this, sorry in advance:

Is there a way I can access a location in a dynamic array(increment an array pointer) of pointers using the `sizeof()` the object that is in the array?

For example:
I have an dynamic array of type base class Student populated with derived class objects(Graduate, Undergraduate).

Due to this I can't just step through my array in the normal fashion to display information because the actual objects Graduate and Undergraduate are different sizes than Student. Each array step will move `sizeof(Student)` when the actual objects are larger.

Depending on the type of student I am doing(this is for Graduate):

```
Student *student = new Graduate(undergrad, fName, lName, major, idNum, arr2, cSize, 
        degreeType, thesis);
arr[i] = student;
```

Where `arr` was declared: `Student *arr = new Student[size];`

Using my array I had created this in a for loop:

```
if (!students[i].getGradStatus()){
    handleGraduate(&students[i], i);
    step = step + sizeof(Graduate);
}
else if (students[i].getGradStatus()){
    handleUndergraduate(&students[i], i);
    step = step + sizeof(Undergraduate);
}
```

I was trying to come up with a way to change the step size. I don't think this will work with a for loop but a while loop may be different. Pretty much I'm trying to go something similar to a file `seekg()` but manually on an array.

And as I've noticed everyone likes to question the use of dynamic arrays over vectors so let me just say I cannot use vectors on this project(No STL is allowed :( ). And I have to use Polymorphism, thus why I have an array pointer of type Student holding derived class objects.

Comment: And that's why non-leaf classes in a polymorphic hierarchy should be abstract...

Comment: Hang on, so your array contains the actual objects rather than pointers to them? For your array populating the size a pointer matters here, not the Student object. Am I missing something?

Comment: This is typically done with an array of pointers (`Student **arr`).  Then each element can point to a different class in the hierarchy.  What you say you want to do is possible but not for the faint of heart.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I have read that (and tried) but somewhere between passing the array of pointers and accessing the individual pointers the subclass information was getting sliced. Either that or I was doing it wrong. I haven't been able to find a straightforward example/tutorial on dynamic arrays of pointers.

Comment: The way you assign to your array is not correct. You created a new array of Students, then instantiated a new Graduate and then assigned the pointer to the instance at `arr[i]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't store different sized objects in an array like that. When you try to copy a *derived type* like `Graduate` over a *base type* like `Student` you get what's known as *slicing* because of the differences in object size (parts can get chopped off).

To do this you need to store `Student*` (pointers to `Students`.)

```
class Student
{
    std::string name;
public:
    Student(const std::string& name): name(name) {}
    virtual ~Student() {} // virtual destructor

    virtual void handle() = 0; // implementation must override this

    std::string get_name() const { return name; }
};

class Graduate
: public Student
{
public:
    Graduate(const std::string& name): Student(name) {}
    virtual void handle() { std::cout << "Handling Graduate" << '\n'; }
};

class UnderGraduate
: public Student
{
public:
    UnderGraduate(const std::string& name): Student(name) {}
    virtual void handle() { std::cout << "Handling UnderGraduate" << '\n'; }
};

int main()
{
    Student** students = new Student*[3];

    students[0] = new Graduate("Wendy");
    students[1] = new UnderGraduate("Bob");
    students[2] = new Graduate("Rachel");

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << students[i]->get_name() << '\n';
        students[i]->handle(); // polymorphic function (virtual)
    }

    delete[] students; // clean up or (better) use a smart pointer
}
```

**Output:**

```
Wendy
Handling Graduate
Bob
Handling UnderGraduate
Rachel
Handling Graduate
```

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhhh it works now. Had to change my `.` to `->` I have been trying to get this working for almost 2 days now. Thank you so much.

I would jsut like to clarify that when passing this array to a function `func(students)` and `void func(Student **students)`

Comment: What about when the derived class has a member variable and getters and setters i need to access? Can I sent that pointer to variable meant to hold that object type? Like `Graduate stu = student[i];`

Comment: @Alyssa The whole point of polymorphism is that you don't need to know the exact type. Rather than the code needing to know the exact type of the objects so as to know how to operate on them, the objects operate on themselves.

Comment: However if you **must** use the exact type you should use a `dynamic_cast` which returns a *null pointer* if the type is incorrect: `if(Graduate* gp = dynamic_cast<Graduate*>(students[0])) { gp->func(); }`

Comment: Thank you. I'm aware you aren't supposed to use the derived class members. The instructions for this project said Undergrad had to be responsible for a _classification_ and Graduate had to be responsible for _degreeType_ and _thesis_. Otherwise it all would have just gone into the Student class. Thank you very much this information has gotten me back on track to complete my project.

Answer (score 1):

Change your array to be an array of Student pointers instead of Student objects.

```
 Student **arr = new Student*[size];
```

When you do that your objects will live on the heap and the pointer size is always the same, so the issue you are having will go away.

Comment: I just left a comment about this above :(

Answer (score 1):

Since you can write that I assume that it's possible to instantiate a Student (non-derived). That's bad, since you're going to store derived objects in the array your students will be sliced (poor students!). To counter that you're doing weird things with the size of the instance types. Just don't.

Make an array of student pointers instead, `Student **arr`. Pointers have fixed size and they will point to any of the derived types of student so you don't have to worry about their sizes.

---

```
Student **student = new Student*[size];
...
student[i] = new Graduate(...);
```

This should work.

Comment: but when i need to access the information in, let's say.., one of the Graduate pointers I created  how do I access it? 
`student[i].getName();`doesnt work

Comment: @Alyssa You're now working with pointers. To access member data through a pointer write `student[i]->getName();`.